# Why is my car so icy in the winter?

Tags: car, ice

The car is a 2004 VW Passat B5.5. The last few days have been colder than usual where I live (below 0 degrees Celsius). The outside of my car has been covered in ice in the mornings and I use a scraper to remove the ice so that I can see where I am driving the car. However, this is not the only ice on the car. After scraping all the windows down and getting inside the car, I still wasn't able to see out the front windscreen of my car. There was ice on both sides!

I assume that the car is damp inside (although I had no idea until now), and that when the temperature drops the moisture in the air both inside and outside the car will freeze. It's very annoying as when scraping the inside of the windscreen the interior gets covered in ice!

***What can I do to prevent ice from freezing on to the inside of my windscreen?***

Also, in general ***any tips to avoid ice on the car would be good to know***. For example, I saw another car parked under a large sheet of metal (just a roof, no walls) and it had no ice on it whatsoever! I don't understand this as the outside air temperature was still just as cold as where my car was parked but that car had no ice.

Is there a legitimate explanation for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct to assume that this happens because of moisture in the car vaporizing, condensing on the inside of the (colder than the environment) windshield and freezing when the temperature inside drops enough. People bring a lot of water into the car by breathing and bearing snow/rain with their clothing. To avoid this you need to remove as much moisture from the interior as possible. I have been fighting this problem for a long time myself, so here is what I can suggest:

- Use the air conditioning system when you can. It dries out the blown air, but be careful when using it before the end of your trip, as the unit may accumulate some moisture itself, which will evaporate inside the car when you park it (thanks to *sweber* for the improvement).
- Avoid using the recirculation mode on the heater, unless the A/C is on. Moisture will accumulate in the car much faster, as fresh air is not brought in from the outside, but water vapor is brought in from the lungs of the driver/passengers.
- Drive a long distance with the heater maxed and directed at feet once in a while to dry out the constantly wet places in the interior.
- Change the pollen filter if you haven't done that for a year or longer. A clogged filter might inhibit the air circulation and accumulate moisture.
- Clean the inside of the windshield as good as you can (preferably while the temperatures are not freezing yet). Use alcohol, a dirty windshield attracts moisture.
- If you use carpet floor mats - get some rubber ones for the winter and clean the snow/water off them once in a while. Carpet mats accumulate moisture when the snow from your shoes melts and often don't have the time to dry out.
- Avoid bringing snow into the car altogether. You can't do this completely, but clean off your pants and "clap" your shoes before bringing your legs inside.
- Leave water absorbing materials or a commercial dehumidifier in the car overnight (especially next to the windshield) to absorb extra moisture. Cat litter is great for this (stuff some into a sock), so is salt. Newspapers also work if you're in a pinch (and if you still have any for some reason o.O).
- Use over-the-counter chemicals intended for reducing window misting. Less misting = less freezing.
- When your trip is done, open all doors to ventilate the interior for a couple of minutes at least. This replaces the humid air inside with drier air from the outside and reduces the inside temperature, which reduces evaporation. You can make this quicker by starting sooner - open all windows before you start parking.
- If there is no time for ventilating the car - turn the heater to the lowest setting during your last minutes of driving on maximum power setting. This will reduce the interior temperature and reduce evaporation.
- Alternatively, leave the windows slightly open when you park the car if it is safe. This helps air circulate and less of the evaporated water ends up on your windshield. Just make sure that it's not raining or snowing (or use wind deflectors).
- If the freezing on the inside of the windshield is extreme and practically impossible to avoid - make sure your heater system is not faulty. Leaks in the heater core can introduce moisture to the interior even when parked. Other places where moisture can get in (sunroof, water drains) should be inspected as well.

That's what is known to help us poor people living in countries with cold winters, combine them and your problems should be gone. Usually rubber mats, avoiding to amass mountains of snow inside and ventilating the interior for a couple of minutes when you park is enough, the rest are for when you have some serious interior dampness problems.

However what I haven't understood yet myself is why some cars are more prone to inside freezing than others - some people appear to be doing none of this and are not experiencing inside freezing. Might have something to do with natural ventilation of the car or superior isolation. Hopefully someone else can answer this.

To avoid freezing on the OUTSIDE of the car, there are two ways I know of:

- Park it where less moisture and snow deposits on top of the car - under roofs, in garages, next to walls, etc.
- Cover the car up. There are special full body covers for sale, but they are impractical and often pointless. What is more practical is covering the windshield only. Anything works - cardboard cover, large towel, thicker bed sheet. Just hold it in place with the wipers and it will prevent the windshield from freezing over, saving you some scraping (which slowly scratches the glass with the tiny pieces of dirt on it, therefore is harmful besides being tiring)

Obviously all of this can be prevented by parking in heated garages, but that is not an option for most of us. If anyone knows more ways to avoid freezing on the inside and outside - add your own answer, I would like to know as well.

Comment: Nice answer, but one point: A/C is nice to de-humify the air and it's really great for fogged windows. However, it collects lots of water, and releases it when not in use. In my experience, running the A/C all the time causes even more fogging the next morning. Switch it off as soon as possible, so it can dry.

Comment: Shouldn't the A/C release the water outside? As far as I know they have drains for releasing the water accumulated in the system, which is why you can see cars leaving water puddles under them in the summer.

Comment: @I have no idea: In general, yes. However, the condenser and it's compartment will be very wet, and over night, this water will (partially) evaporate. This causes high humidity in the air in the ducts, and this air will also make its way into the car. Even more, when it's cold outside, water will freeze on the evaporator, so it will stay there even longer. I also remember sometimes the initially clear windows gets fogged just when starting the motor, when this humid air is blown against the window.

Comment: Protip: Use the A/C and turn it off five minutes before the end of the trip. This will give the cold A/C parts and ducts time to warm up and release the humidity. This should be done all the time, during winter and summer because if the humiditiy in these areas is high, mold will form resulting in a bad smell and bad air quality.

Comment: "turn the heater to the lowest setting to remove any leftover moisture inside the ducts" - This is grossly counterproductive. Ideally, you'd want to make sure the inside of the car is boiling hot and then quickly vent all that hot air with the water in it when exiting the car.

Comment: @user5626466 Agreed. However, in my experience, 5 minutes isn't enough, especially with cold outside conditions. To me, 10 minutes seems more appropriate. - Another tip: The A/C evaporator will warm/dry up faster if you turn on circulation, because then it gets the warm air from the inside. Of course, once the evaparator is dry, you have all that moisture inside the car and have to vent that afterwards again.

Comment: @sweber - I have also experienced clear windows being fogged up just when starting, but I rarely ever use the A/C, so it is not necessarily the reason. Though I do agree that the A/C should be used carefully.

Comment: @Hanno Honestly, I agree with you on the vent moisture removal. The actual benefit is reducing the interior temperature before leaving the car, as cooling the air is much better than leaving the boiling air in. Still inferior to actual open-door ventilation. I'll edit the answer.